# When are all average trajectories of $w_{k+1}=Aw_k+b$ bounded?

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Below is an open-problem in my field, and I'm wondering if someone has insights I'm missing. ([cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823598/when-are-all-average-trajectories-of-w-k1-aw-kb-bounded) on math.se)

Suppose observation $x$ is drawn from some distribution $\mathcal{D}$, $w_0\in \mathbb{R}^\mathrm{d}$, and my update has the following form

$$w_{k+1}=(I-xx')w_k+b$$

When are average trajectories $u_k=E[w_k]$ bounded? Expectation is taken over all sequences of IID observations $x_1,\ldots,x_k$. Motivation for this recurrence is  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818716/when-is-sgd-for-linear-least-squares-stable).

I have worked out the case of $b=0$ and I'm wondering if global asymptotic stability for $b=0$ also implies boundedness for some other value of $b$. An interesting special case is when $x$ comes from Gaussian centered at 0.

Cases of increasing difficulty are

1. $b=0$
2. $b=c$ is some vector $c$ from $\mathbb{R}^\mathrm{d}$
3. $b=Bx$ for some $\mathrm{d}\times \mathrm{d}$ matrix $B$
4. $b=d$ where $d$ is drawn from some distribution $\mathcal{D}_2$ independent of $x$
5. $b=c+Bx+d$
6. $b,x$ are drawn jointly from some distribution $\mathcal{D}_3$

For the case of $b=0$, condition below seems to be a necessary and sufficient condition for all trajectories $u_k$ to converge to 0. The following must hold for all symmetric matrices $A$

$$E[(x'Ax)^2]<2 E[x'A^2 x]$$

For the case of $x$ coming from zero-centered Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma$, this becomes the following equation, which can be checked in practice using generalized eigenvalue solver (using identities 20.18 and 20.25c of Seber's Matrix Handbook [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471748692))

$$(\text{Tr}(A\Sigma))^2+2\text{Tr}(A\Sigma)^2<2\text{Tr}A^2\Sigma$$